# How to trim Strings before inserting to MongoDB using MongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

Basically, I am fetching data from another source and creating my db collections. But some of the data has spaces in the end, causing issues in frontend when used later.

Is there a generic way to trim all `String` fields of all Collections before inserting and updating to `MongoDB` using spring mongoTemplate configuration/code.

I don't want to write logic specific to each type of collection and each field in it. Also, is it a good practice to put such logic at DB repositories level?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`AbstractMongoEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/AbstractMongoEventListener.html). For example, create create your own implementation of `AbstractMongoEventListener`:

```
@Component
class SaveMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<Object> event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();

        for (Field field : source.getClass().getFields()) {
            if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                try {
                    String value = (String) field.get(source);
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(value != null ? value.trim(): value, source);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This implementation will trim all strings in your object before converting it to MongoDB object. The listener should work for all your collections. Do not forget to register this listener in Spring context.

To trim string after loading from MongoDB, you should do the same in [`onAfterConvert`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/AbstractMongoEventListener.html#onAfterConvert-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterConvertEvent-) event.